# How to check all child checkboxes in a datagrid header

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, expander

I have a datagrid with 3 level grouping. Grouping is done in code behind using the CollectionView and PropertyGroupDescription.
Every row of record will have a DataTemplateColumn (CheckBox). I included a checkbox infront of each header so that I can check all the child data.
Unfortunately I have tried few methods but i cant check all the child checkboxes.

[image]

**xaml codes**

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander x:Name="MyExpander" IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <CheckBox Click="checkBoxHeader_Click"/>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="MyExpanderHeader" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

**cs code**

```
CollectionView collectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_stationInfoList);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription1 = new PropertyGroupDescription("Property1");
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription2 = new PropertyGroupDescription("Property2");
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription3 = new PropertyGroupDescription("Property3");
            collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription1);
            collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription2);
            collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription3);
```

Comment: "Unfortunately I have tried few methods" Which are those methods? Can you list them somehow?

Comment: could you not just bind the multibind the child check box to the property and to the HeaderCheckbox element. Making sure that the binding to the HeaderCheckbox is only OneWay